# Retreiving src attribute of multiple images in a php array

Tags: php, module, beaver

I have the code as follows for creating a custom module in Beaver Builder:

```
'my_multiple_photos_field' => array(
'type'          => 'multiple-photos',
'label'         => __( 'Multiple Photos Field', 'fl-builder' )
```

),

Now i want to display all the images in this array. This is not working.

```
<div class="fl-example-image">
<?php echo "<img src='".$settings->my_multiple_photos_field_src."'>" 
?>
```

Comment: you need to loop over this array and preview each one as a separate element

Comment: you need to loop like this foreach($settings->my_multiple_photos_field_src as $src) { echo "<img src='".$src."'>";  }

Comment: That is not working Jyothi. I am able to echo single images when I create a different module. You can check the documentation here https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/custom-module-documentation/

Answer (score 0):

this setting field from Beaver Builder:

```
'my_multiple_photos_field' => array(
    'type'          => 'multiple-photos',
    'label'         => __( 'Multiple Photos Field', 'fl-builder' )
),
```

will give you an array of ids --> attachment-ids.

so if you need those images, you have to get the url for the src-tag.

with: [wp_get_attachment_url( int $attachment_id )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/)

```
$output = '';
$output = '<div class="fl-example-image">';
foreach($settings->my_multiple_photos_field_src as $imageid){
    $src = wp_get_attachment_url( (int) $imageid );
    $output .= "<img src='" . $src . "' />";
}  
$output .= '</div>'; // close imageholder 

echo $output;
```

The code goes into your frontend.php, as described in the docs from beaver builder: [Custom module developer guide](https://kb.wpbeaverbuilder.com/article/124-custom-module-developer-guide)